# How do you put a link to another question?

Tags: support

How do you put a link to another question, I have seen them, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Are you asking [how to put a link in a post?](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the "Share" link under the question (or answer) and you will be presented with a modal dialog box containing a link to the post.
[image: Share Link]

Include that link in your question (or answer) and the site will automatically handle the title formatting for you: [How do you put a link to another question?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3121/64)
Or you can link to it using the markdown link syntax: `[link title](URL)`, [like this](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3121/64).

More details can be found [in our formatting help page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

---

Note that you should also use this link when sharing a question outside of the site. It includes your user ID, so you get credit for sharing the question.
This leads to the [Announcer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer), [Booster](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster), and [Publicist](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badges.

Comment: Can I cheat the system by add my UserID to the link *inside* this site?