# No "publicist" badge ever awarded, who does tweet questions then?

Tags: discussion, badges

Following [this answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3122/3201), when looking for how many times the [publicist](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) badge was awarded, it's quite surprising to see nobody received it.

[Many questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) (2,400+) have been visited more than 1,000 times, <strike>and this cannot happen unless the link is shared</strike>. Example:

- Question [Why do most single propellers have a clockwise rotation?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9153/why-do-most-single-propellers-have-a-clockwise-rotation?atw=1).
- [Shared](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/9153/revisions) the day it was posted.
- But this was by [Aviation SE @StackAviation](https://twitter.com/StackAviation).

Do you know who does tweet with this account, and why no members from Aviation.SE did win the badge yet?

(Maybe the answer is because there are not member from the stack sharing on Twitter, but this seems a bit odd.)

Comment: "...this cannot happen unless the link is shared" [citation needed]?

Comment: @falstro: Yep, after checking, I see that 1,000 views are actually obtained without mention to Twitter. That's a mystery for me. Any idea? Thanks for having challenged.

Comment: You seem to assume that Twitter drives most of our traffic... can we find any stats for this? I thought it was mostly the "Hot Network Questions" list.

Comment: @fooot: That's what I assumed, but I see this may be wrong. No idea about the traffic ratio brought by Twitter. Maybe the referrer page is available on [data](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not really used to it.

Comment: @fooot Actually, (by far) most of our traffic comes from search engines.

Comment: @Lnafziger: To your knowledge, is this also true for the subset of questions that have been tweeted? I've seen a large increase in views as soon as one of my question was tweeted.

Comment: @mins We don't have a way to check per-question, but looking at the site's aggregate statistics Twitter isn't even a drop in the bucket on the referrers list (Facebook shows up, as do Reddit, Y Combinator, and for some reason Ars Technica). I don't know if they set the Referrer header though, so they may be in the "direct links" pile. All of that traffic is a tiny slice (<15%) compared to search engines though (>85%).

Comment: @voretaq7: Really surprising, thanks.

Comment: @mins It makes sense when you look at the numbers: The twitter bot has all of 69 followers, and most of us don't tweet out questions/answers to our few-hundred followers on any kind of regular basis. Google on the other hand LOVES us (even in an incognito/private browsing window our questions & answers rank pretty high in search results), so of the relatively few aviation-related searches that happen we get a lot of exposure, and thus a lot of page views.

Comment: It's also important to note the difference between "1000 views" and "1000 unique IPs." The same IP can potentially visit a page a lot of times. There may be some questions that were indeed visited by 1000 unique IPs, but those were probably mostly referred by Google rather than by someone's link. The only way I could think of to potentially get 1000 unique IPs to click your referral link would be to post it on reddit or similar. Maybe on social media if you have _a lot_ of followers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one got the publicist badge because no one has met the requirement for it yet. However, you can see that [Danny was awarded booster](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster) badge.

As mentioned in the [answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3122/65) you referenced, you will only get the publicist badge if 1000 unique IPs visit a question. For example, if I share your question like this:
`https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3125/65` (notice my UserID is suffixed to the URL), then it will record the IPs accessing it. However, if I share it like the following, then it will not:

- `https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3125/`
- `https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3125/no-publicist-tag-ever-awarded-who-does-tweet-questions-then`

---

Regarding the stack twitter bot, you can read more here: [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183407/231188)

Comment: I wasn't aware that sharing it by just copy pasting the address in the address bar would make any difference....  Hmm, more fake internet points to be had I guess.  Is this commonly known and I've just been happily oblivious, or is this a commonly used feature?  I mean, if no one knows they can link things in a certain way to get credit for it...maybe that's why no one has gotten the badge.

Comment: @JayCarr you have your ID appended automagically when clicking the "share" on the bottom left of a post. so it is basically a badge for people that use that feature.